# How to serve static file from dynamic url using nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

i am trying to serve static file from dynamic url

For example serve `onefile.pdf` file to every dynamic url started `/ajax/pdf?dyanamic`

**dynamic url**

> /ajax/pdf?id=5845584&pdfid=19606554&_=1527413953472

i am trying to serve /home/jems/onefile.pdf  file to above dynamic url

my nginx config

```
    if ($request_uri ~* (pdf)) {
            internal /home/jems/onefile.pdf;
    }
```

but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
    location /jems/ {
        autoindex         on;
        alias             /home/jems/onefile.pdf;
    }
```